# [C++]It's better to pass the index of a node or the node itself? Which is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, graph

Which method is faster?
This?

```
int bfs( nodo& s ){....
```

Or this one?

```
int bfs( int index ){....
```

where nodo is this struct:

```
struct nodo{
  int valore;
  vector<int> vic;
  vector<int> nodiEntranti;
  vector<int> disprezzati;
  vector<int> rivali;
  int dt;
  int ft;
  bool visited; 
  nodo(){
        visited=false;
        valore= -1;
        dt=0;
        ft=0;
  }
};
```

and I have this structure:

```
vector<nodo> graph;
```

P.S: i need to call this function 200000 times.

Comment: Why don't you profile them and compare?

Comment: Just benchmark. But I think it does not matter a lot.

Comment: with 100000 nodes, in this case is better to pass the node itself, there is a slight improvement of performance(0.04s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the operator[] on a *std::vector* object is a function call, so, using the first version of `bsf(int index)` will result in a call to the operator[] inside the function every time. If you can somehow cache a node reference and reuse it for multiple call to `bsf(node &)` then you might see some small performance increase for the latter.

Comment: You forgot permissible optimizations: Not getting that call inlined would be ... surprising.

Comment: True, the compiler can inline the call to operator[], since it is expected to be a trivial function, but without knowing the compiler and implementation details, I think its better to assume a function call. But anyways, that is why I wrote that "you might see some small performance increase".

Answer (score 3):

It will not change a lot probably.

The reason of this is that you are passing the struct **by reference**, i.e. passing the memory address of the struct instead of the whole thing. This should not differ a lot in performance with passing an integer index to the node.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what you're doing with it.  If you pass the index, there is the extra (albeit small) step to get the reference; but if you need access to its neighbors, having the index could make that faster.

Bottom line: as @taocp suggested, profile it and see for yourself.

Comment: Accessing the neighbours with pointer arithmetic is trivial: `p+1` `p-1`. How could indices be more efficient? (`vector[index+1]` `vector[index-1]`)